# How do I use Java regex expression to validate variations of a number

Tags: java, regex, validation

Currently trying to validate a 9 digit number that a user may input in several different ways. The number may or may not begin with a capital A, which is then proceeded by the 9 numbers or just 9 numbers separated by a dash after every third number. Acceptable formats :
A123456789
123-456-789

This is what I came up with:

```
(?=.*[A])[0-9]{9,13}
```

Comment: Should `A123-456-789` be allowed?

Comment: Yeah that can be one possible variation, although not  a likely one

Comment: @OrokUkpong unless you specify which variations are allowed, the regex cannot be defined properly and you might get unexpected results. "can be" is too vague. Please edit your question to define the range of possible inputs that you need to match.

Comment: @OrokUkpong If that is true, then question is totally misleading. You explicitly specify two formats, one with leading `A` and no dashes, and one without `A` and with dashes. The text also says "A and 9 numbers, or **just** 9 numbers separated by a dash". The "just" means without anything else, i.e. without the `A`. If you want optional `A` and optional dashes, independent of each other, then you need to edit the question and clarify, because the question as-is will not allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following code and Regex:

```
        String pattern = "A\\d{9}|(\\d{3}){3}|A?(\\d{3}-){2}\\d{3}";

    String[] sArr = {"A123456789", "123-456-789", "A123-456-789", "123456789", "qwerty", "12-345-12"};

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    for (int i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(sArr[i]);

        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Value Matched :: " + sArr[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Value Not Matched :: " + sArr[i]);

        }
    }
```

### output is:

```
Value Matched :: A123456789
Value Matched :: 123-456-789
Value Matched :: A123-456-789
Value Matched :: 123456789
Value Not Matched :: qwerty
Value Not Matched :: 12-345-12
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
^A?\d{3}(?:-?\d{3}){2}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/87F0vW/1

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `A?` - optional `A`
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `(?:` - non-capturing group start

  - `-?` - optional dash
  - `\d{3}` - three digits
- `)` - end of the group
- `{2}` - repeat the group twice
- `$` - end of the string

**Update:**

If patterns like `A123-456-789` should not be allowed, i.e. a number may comprise either `A` followed by 9 digits without delimiter or no `A` and 9 digits with optional dashes every after every third digit, then the regex may be composed with alternation:

```
^(?:A\d{9}|\d{3}(?:-?\d{3}){2})$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ZjLh8p/1

Comment: Depending on the initial A, there will or will not be dashes. This expression will allow A123-456-789, right?

Comment: Yes, it will. Intentionally. Requirements clarification required.

Comment: Requirements seem very clear. Question explicitly lists two acceptable formats.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov I guess `^A\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}$` should do the trick if I get the requirements right.

Comment: @MalteHartwig: yes, but the alternation should be grouped in order to get `^` & `$` applied properly: `^(?:A\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3})$`

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that. Your addition seems good, though.

Comment: Of course, the `^` and `$` anchors are redundant if using `matches()`, not `find()`, and simply complicates the regex, so dripping them would likely be better.

Comment: And the dashes are optional

Comment: @DmitryEgorov The dashes are not optional. They are *not allowed* if `A` is present, and they are *required* if `A` is absent.

Comment: @Andreas: They are definitely allowed if `A` is present. See the OP comments. And how do you know about `A`-less case?

Answer (score 0):

To use regex to match against two or more different patterns, use the `|` [logical operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical).

For format 1, use `A\d{9}`

For format 2, use `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}` or `\d{3}(?:-\d{3}){2}`

Combined that is then `A\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}`

As a Java string literal, it is **`"A\\d{9}|\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}"`**

If you use the Java `matches()` method, not the `find()` method, you won't need the `^` and `$` anchors suggested by other answers.